# Load font family from memory

Tags: wpf

I need to create a program that downloads a required font through a web service as a byte[] and I would like to assign the font on a label control in wpf.

I know I could save the font as a file and get a new FontFamily from a URI but I'd rather not have temporary files.

I have seen that in System.Drawing you could use a PrivateFontCollection from memory but I'm not sure if its possible use that in a WPF label.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44394/wpf-load-font-from-stream